# Diffeomorphic stops on "Invalid mesh" error

Tags: import

I'm using Blender 4.0.2 and Diffeomorphic 1.7.3.1949 to import a purchased Daz3d asset, the "FG One Bed Apartment" from Fugazi1968.   It's a complete scene with many props and details, and the problem is that as I try to import it I get errors like this:

```
ERROR (1.7.3.1949):
Invalid mesh "FG FHinge Dr 1-1.002". Correcting.
For details see
'C:\Users\x\Documents\DAZ Importer\daz_importer_errors.txt'
```

Unfortunately, not only does the importer not "correct" the invalid mesh, it completely stops the import.   So of a scene with 200 items in it, if it stops on the 10th item, I wind up with only the previous 9 items.

I have searched in vain for a setting to override this behavior and tell Diffeomorphic to continue after an error, either ignoring the bad mesh or replacing it with a cube (or whatever).   But no luck.

Does anyone have a workaround for this behavior?   I have a huge number of Daz items I want to import into Blender but a lot of Daz meshes don't seem to pass validation in Diffeomorphic.

Comment: We can't help with Diffeomorphic which is a third-party addon and not part of Blender. You should ask the addon developer about problems using it.

Comment: @JohnEason If you want to add your comment as an answer I'll happily mark it "correct."  Thanks.

Comment: That wasn't an answer. It was just a comment saying that we couldn't help. If I put it in the answer field and you marked it as correct anyone else searching the same problem would expect to see a solution there!